# AngularJS - Update model and DOM from another App

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

Two angular apps are on a same page, first one have a service that modifies data model. Calling the service from its parent app modifies data and DOM accordingly.
But calling same service from another app makes a copy of data and makes changes on that copy only.
How could angular service be called from another app so it have access to data model from it's parent app?

[Here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pfv3LWYdxvAuB4GkeTi7?p=preview)

```
<div ng-app="app1">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <input type="text" value="{{data.list.name}}">
    <br>
    <button ng-click="update()">run from app1</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='app2div' ng-app='app2' ng-controller="ctrl2">
    <button ng-click="update2()">run from app2</button>
</div>

<script>
    var test = angular.module("app1",[]);
    test.controller("myctrl", function($scope, service)
    {
        $scope.scope1 = true;
        $scope.data=service.data;


    $scope.update=function()
    {
        service.updateValue();
    };
    }).factory("service", function()
    {
    return new (function(){
        this.data={list:{name:"name0"}},
        this.updateValue=function()
        {
        var self=this;
        self.data.list=self.values[self.count];
        self.count++;


        },
        this.values= [{name:"name1"}, {name:"name2"}, {name:"name3"}],
        this.count=0
    })();
    });

    var app2 = angular.module('app2',['app1']);

    app2.controller('ctrl2', function($scope, service){
        $scope.scope2 = true;
        $scope.update2 = function()
        {
            service.updateValue();
        };
    });

    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2div"), ['app2']);
</script>
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: First of all: please don't use reserved words like `new` or names used by the framework, for example `service`. It is a very bad practice and can lead to nasty debugging problems.

Comment: The service is called in `app2`. There is no error there. The issue should be with the controller scope. Add this line: `$scope.data = service.data;` in `ctrl2` after `$scope.scope2` and before `$scope.update2`. In your HTML add this line `<p>{{data.list.name}}</p>` after the button "run from app2". Then you can see that the controller works fine and the service is called.

Comment: The best solution in my opinion would be to outsource the service in a third module and make it accessible to `app1` and `app2`. So you can share the scope between the controllers.

Comment: Added the line, now app2 utilizes service properly, but what I need is data in app1 to be modified and corresponding DOM changes to be applied. So  click on any of button has exactly the same result...

Comment: @Anton still need help with this?

Comment: @tasseKATT  yes, if you could provide the solutin that would be great!

Comment: @Anton I can try to help, will post an answer soon.

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: @tasseKATT so sorry for a late response! really helpful answer!

Comment: It's no problem - You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

There is not really any built in support for cross-app communication in AngularJS, so it can be a bit tricky. But it is possible.

First it's important to understand the difference between module, app and instances.

In this case we will use the word `app` to describe the entire composition of modules.

In your case you have:

1. **app1** - which consists of the module `app1`.
2. **app2** - which consists of the modules `app2` and `app1`.

Now when you use either `ng-app` or `angular.bootstrap` to bootstrap an application a new instance of the app is created.

Each instance gets its own instance of the `$injector` service.

Now comes an important part - each service in AngularJS is a singleton in the sense that it is only created once ***per $injector instance*** (including $rootScope).

This means that after you have bootstrapped the both applications you will have:

1. Instance of **app1** -> Instance of **$injector** -> Instance of **service**
2. Instance of **app2** -> Instance of **$injector** -> Instance of **service**

So there are two instances of **service**, each with their own internal state. Which is why the data is not shared in your case.

So it wouldn't even matter if you instead bootstrapped **app1** two times, there would still be two instances of everything.

---

### How to

To retrieve an app´s injector instance you can use the `injector` method that is available on angular elements.

*Note that this is not the same as the method `angular.injector`, which is used to create entire new instances of $injector.*

Retrieve a reference to a DOM element of a specific app that was used with `ng-app` or `angular.bootstrap`:

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('app1');
```

Turn it into an angular (jqLite) element:

```
var angularElement = angular.element(domElement);
```

Retrieve the app's injector:

```
var injector = angularElement.injector();
```

Use the injector to retrieve the correct instance of a service:

```
var myService = injector.get('myService')
```

Call the service:

```
myService.doSomething();
```

If this is done outside of Angular's digest loop you will need to trigger it manually:

```
var rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
rootScope.$apply();
```

Or:

```
var scope = angularElement.scope();
scope.$apply();
```

---

### Example solution

We have two apps:

```
var app1 = angular.module('app1', ['shared']);

var app2 = angular.module('app2', ['shared']);

app1.controller('MyController', function($scope, sharedFactory) {

  $scope.sharedFactory = sharedFactory;
});

app2.controller('MyController', function($scope, sharedFactory) {

  $scope.sharedFactory = sharedFactory;
})
```

Both apps use the `shared` module consisting of a factory named `sharedFactory` with the following api:

```
var api = {
  value: 0,
  increment: increment,
  incrementSync: incrementSync
};
```

Remember that each app has its own instance of the factory.

The `increment` method will simply increment the value. If called from `app1` the incrementation will take place in app1's instance of the service.

The `incrementSync` method will increment the value in both app1's and app2's service instance:

```
function incrementSync() {

  var app1InjectorInstance = angular.element(document.getElementById('app1')).injector();
  var app2InjectorInstance = angular.element(document.getElementById('app2')).injector();

  console.log(app1InjectorInstance === app2InjectorInstance); // false

  var app1SharedFactoryInstance = app1InjectorInstance.get('sharedFactory');
  var app2SharedFactoryInstance = app2InjectorInstance.get('sharedFactory');

  console.log('app1-sharedFactory:', app1SharedFactoryInstance);
  console.log('app2-sharedFactory:', app2SharedFactoryInstance);

  app1SharedFactoryInstance.increment();
  app2SharedFactoryInstance.increment();

  var otherInjectorInstance = app1SharedFactoryInstance === api 
    ? app2InjectorInstance 
    : app1InjectorInstance;

  otherInjectorInstance.get('$rootScope').$apply();
}
```

Note that if `incrementSync` is for example called from within app1, we will be in app1's digest loop, but we will have to start app2´s digest loop manually. This is what the part involving `otherInjectorInstance` does.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/q2ZEG8VqxHORRzLy8wqZ?p=preview

Hopefully this will help you get going and find a solution to your problem.